# AppCode & iPad3 : How to avoid "Unknown device error"

Tags: appcode

How to build & run for iPad3 with AppCode (v1.5)
Xcode works fine with iPad3. Appcode gives "Unknown device error".
Appcode works fine with the same project for iPad1.

Am i missing anything or is AppCode not yet able to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simple solution that worked for me (With input from another user from the AppCode Issue Tracker):

1. detach USB
2. Shutdown/Restart iPad
3. Attach USB.
4. Restart AppCode (might not be needed)
5. Build/Run again.

Many thanks to the great AppCode Devs for exceptional responsive and helpful support (Not only in this case).

**Update:**

Some people still have this (or a related) issue. Also it could be that my own solution is not permanent. (I am not building on my iPad3 a lot at the moment) For reference: the Jetbrains Issue Tracker for AppCode: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-3370